# How to get Bootstrap modal open after clicking okay to an JavaScript confirm?

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-modal

How to get Bootstrap modal open after clicking okay to an JavaScript confirm?

My code:

```
 function generatexy(){
       var xyz = document.getElementById('solvednum').value;
      if(confirm('New SIR Number: '+ solvednum +' has been generated. Do you want to save?') == true){
      //After clicking okay on confirm - I want open bootstrap modal here.
         return true;
       }else{
         window.location = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>controller/method";
          return false;
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code, here `#modal` should be your modal id.

```
$('#modal').modal('show')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer..  i tried this code but it didn't work.

Comment: what is the error in console?

Comment: Modal is working but redirecting suddenly to other page. i have to enter some input in the modal. After submitting modal, then it redirects to other page.

Comment: its not problem with modal then, your javascript confirm seems not working, its executing `else` part too